# Quotient $G/B$ of Lie group $G$ by Borel group $B$ contained in a Grassmannian

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, grassmannian

Let $G$ be a compex Lie group with semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, the connected subgroup
$B$ of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{b} := \mathfrak{b} \oplus \bigoplus_{\alpha \in R^{+}} \mathfrak{g}_{\alpha} $, ( here $R^{+}$ is the set of positive roots) is called a *Borel subgroup*.

In Fulton-Harris' [Representation Theory](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0979-9) on page 383 there is a
**Claim 23.45.** B is a closed subgroup of G, and the quotient G/B is compact.

PROOF. Consider the adjoint representation of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}$. The action of the Borel
subalgebra $b$ (? I think that the authors meant here the action by $B$) obviously preserves the subspace $\mathfrak{b} \subset \mathfrak{g}$, and, in fact, $\mathfrak{b}$ is just the
inverse image of the subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl} (\mathfrak{g})$ preserving this subspace: if $X = \sum X_{\alpha}$ is any element of $\mathfrak{g}$ with $ X_{\alpha} \subset \mathfrak{g}_{\alpha} $ for some $\alpha \in R^{-} $ , we could find an
element $H$ of $\mathfrak{b} \subset \mathfrak{g}$  with $ ad(X)(H) \not \in \mathfrak{g}$ - any $H$ not in the annihilator of $\alpha \in \mathfrak{h}^* $
would do. $ B $ is thus (the connected component of the identity in) the inverse
image in $ G $ of the subgroup of $GL(\mathfrak{g}) $ carrying b into itself. It follows that $ B$ is
closed; and the quotient $G/B$ is contained in a Grassmannian and hence
compact.

Moreover an example: in the case of the classical groups, it is easy (?) to describe the Borel
subgroups and the corresponding quotients.
For $G = SL_{n+1} \mathbb{C}$ , then $B $ is the group of all upper-triangular matrices in $G$, i.e.,
those automorphisms preserving the standard flag. It follows that $G/B$ is the
usual (complete) flag manifold, i.e., the variety of all flags.

Questions:

I not understand the part in the proof where the authors conclude in the above that the quotient $G/B$ should be contained in a Grassmannian. I found several different longer proofs in the web on this issue but here seemingly the authors deduce it directly from previous arguments & assumptions, otherwise I not see any reason why at that point the authors not going into detail how this embedding of $G/B$ in certain Grassmanian manifold should be done.

Secondly, I not see how to deduce for $G = SL_{n+1} \mathbb{C}$ , that the Borel group $B $ is the group of all upper-triangular matrices in $G$. Could somebody sketch which ideas are involved? Is here really only the (a bit tedious) writing out of the exponantiation of $\mathfrak{b}$ considered as restriction of exponentiation of $\mathfrak{g}$ to $G$ involved, or can it be seen more directly that $B$ consists of upper-triangular matrices in $G$?

Comment: Borel subalgebras have fixed dimension. They have identified $G/B$ with the set of Borel subalgebras so it is contained in the Grassmannian of $(\dim \mathfrak{b})$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathfrak{g}$

Comment: For the second part, it should be clear without any tedious computation that exponentiating an upper triangular matrix gives you an upper triangular matrix and the set of upper triangular matrices in $SL_n$ clearly forms a subgroup. Conversely you could see that differentiating a curve if upper triangular matrices gives you an upper triangular matrix. Thus this has Lie algebra $\mathfrak{b}$ and so the only question is whether it is connected.

Comment: But it is easy to construct a path from any such matrix to the identity so connectedness is immediate as well

Comment: @Callum: on question 1: so in explicit terms this identification between $G/B$ and the set of Borel subalgebras (which in turn have same dimension and so as you said are contained in a Grassmannian) is produced by $g \mapsto Image(\rho(g)(\mathfrak{b})$ where $\rho: G \to GL(\mathfrak{g})$ is the adjoint rep map, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what the map you've written there means. Do you mean $g\cdot B \mapsto \operatorname{Ad}(g)\mathfrak{b}$? In which case, yes this map is $G$-equivariant. More directly, this map is the identification between each Borel subgroup and its corresponding Borel subalgebra.

Comment: yes yes thanks, my $\rho$ was exactly the $Ad$.